# WPF XAML - How to bind a DataTrigger to a ComboBox value

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, datatemplate, datatrigger

I currently have a ListView that takes in an item and displays a ComboBox and a Button.

I would like to dynamically show or hide the button based on the value of the ComboBox being equal to "BlahBlahBlah".

Currently the inside of my `<GridView>` looks like this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Property" Width="160">
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <ComboBox x:Name="PropertyComboBox"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ArisingPropertyList, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding ArisingProperty.PropertyName,
                  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  SelectedValuePath="PropertyName" Width="140" >
          </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>                                         


<GridViewColumn Width="30" >                                    
  <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>                                        
     <DataTemplate>
         <Button Content="...">
            <Button.Style>
               <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                 <Style.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SelectedValue.PropertyName, 
                    ElementName=PropertyComboBox}" Value="HideButton">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="BlahBlahBlah" />
                   </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
              </Style>
           </Button.Style>
        </Button>                                                
     </DataTemplate>
   </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
 </GridViewColumn>
```

Can someone point out where I'm going wrong? All I'm getting is:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=PropertyComboBox'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedValue.PropertyName; DataItem=null; target element is 'Button'; target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already bounded **`SelectedValue`** property to your source class, so **bind directly to that property** instead of ComboBox. Issue is ComboBox and Button lies in different Visual trees so can't be bind using ElementName.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ArisingProperty.PropertyName}"
             Value="HideButton">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
</DataTrigger>
```